# Modify authorization URL format using requests-oauthlib

Tags: python, oauth, python-requests, etrade-api

I am using `requests-oauthlib` to authenticate with the ETrade API. It requires the authorization URL to have the following format:

```
https://us.etrade.com/e/t/etws/authorize?key={oauth_consumer_key}&token={oauth_token}
```

However, when I call `authorization_url()`, it uses `oauth_token` instead of `token` for that parameter. Currently I am using `format()` to format the URL myself, but now I have both `token` and `oauth_token` parameters. This works, but is completely inelegant. Is there some way to modify the behavior of `authorization_url()` to allow the URL format I require?

For completeness, here is my code:

```
oauth_session = requests_oauthlib.OAuth1Session(config.oauth_consumer_key, config.consumer_secret, callback_uri='oob')


def get_request_token():
    path = 'oauth/request_token'
    url = base_url + path
    return oauth_session.fetch_request_token(url)


def get_authorization_url(request_token):
    url_format = 'https://us.etrade.com/e/t/etws/authorize?key={oauth_consumer_key}&token={oauth_token}'
    url = url_format.format(oauth_consumer_key=config.oauth_consumer_key, oauth_token=request_token['oauth_token'])
    return oauth_session.authorization_url(url)

request_token = get_request_token()
print(get_authorization_url(request_token))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `authorization_url()` function is a convenience function which calls a generic function to add query parameters to a url (OAuthLib's `common.add_params_to_uri()` which in turn uses `urlparse.urlunparse()`). There is no way to get `authorization_url()` to leave out the `oauth_token` parameter.

The returned type is a `str` (in Python 3), so as long as you are certain that the url and tokens will only contain valid characters, you can obtain the same result by using a plain string format call as you have done in your function.

However if the additional `oauth_token` parameter causes no problems, I would suggest using the `authorization_url()` function for the extra safety provided.

Additionally, it is then unnecessary to do the extra `str.format()` call in your function - the `authorization_url()` takes `kwargs` which can be used to specify those parameters:

```
def get_authorization_url(request_token):
    url = 'https://us.etrade.com/e/t/etws/authorize'
    return oauth_session.authorization_url(url,
                                           key=config.oauth_consumer_key, 
                                           token=request_token['oauth_token'])
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the extra `oauth_token` parameter doesn't cause any problems. What extra safety does `authorization_url()` provide? Does it URL-encode the tokens? Anything else?